# Converting Long/Lat from Excel into shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, latitude-longitude, standard-license-level

How do I convert (the attached image) from long/lats from my spreadsheet to drop into my shapefile for the Well locations?

I have ArcMap (Editor/Standard) 10.0.  I never had to do this conversion before.  The lats/long is located Eastern Ohio.  I know I have to do something with X/Y but I am new to this conversion.

[image]